# Pass scope with omiauth Pinterest authentication request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, pinterest

I am using omniauth-pinterest gem to authenticate Pinterest users. In addition to the default "write_public" I need to pass "write_public" scope. What's the best way to pass "read_public,write_public" scope with the auth request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello there I did not try `omniauth-pinterest`, but in `omniauth-google-oauth2`
we can pass the scope in initializer file. As I expect you can also pass the scope same as `omniauth-google-oauth2` like:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :pinterest, ENV['PINTEREST_APP_ID'], ENV['PINTEREST_APP_SECRET'], scope: ["read_public", "write_public"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, that is exactly what I needed. The the only difference is that the scope has to be passed like a string "read_public,write_public"